# Tree view using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am doing a tree view like [by referring this link](http://catcode.com/domcontent/display/menus.html)

I am getting this error in firebug

```
**Non-standard document.all property was used.
Use W3C standard document.getElementById() instead.

return document.all[id].style[property];**
```

How to use `document.getElementById()` at that place

Comment: `Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Mar 2001 21:58:01 GMT`. Throw that link away, right now. If you're looking for a ready-made solution, check out http://www.jstree.com/ .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: you should consider learning javascript before asking questions like theese.

Comment: I'm afraid this question falls under the "does not show any research effort" category. Also, I can't see how PHP could be related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that you accessed the property "all" of the variable `document`, but this property is, let's say, deprecated, so should not be used. The console says that you should use a method "getElementById", which returns the element with given id, on which you can then proceed.

To access the element by id if you know the id, you can for example, declare a variable and assign to it the result of `getElementById` (there is going to be a problem with `style[property]`):

```
var myElement=document.getElementById("id");
return myElement.property; // height for example
```

or just

```
return document.getElementById("id").property;  // height for example
```